# How to connect to HTTPS Server with self-signed cert using AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I just started to work in a small company, that has no properly signed SSL-certificates yet. But their test HTTP Servers offer HTTPS exclusively.
I want to create a iOS client using AFNetworking.

How to achieve it?